# Set httpcontext in asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to follow this tutorial to create a custom server in asp.net core 3.x [Use IServer from ASP.NET Core to create your own web server](https://reynders.co/use-iserver-from-aspnet-core-to-create-your-own-web-server/) looks like things in v3 are a little bit different and I am stuck in the following line:

```
var context = (HostingApplication.Context)(object)application.CreateContext(features);
```

First thing is that HostingApplication.Context at some point resides in namespace **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal** in version 3.x looks like it is not the case. I removed the cast and debug the code and realize that the context object is of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication+Context so I tried to cast to that but HostingApplication is not accesible due its protection level. How to adjust my code to get the same result using the new features or recommended way in asp.net core 3. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need the cast? How are you using it?

Comment: After the cast I can access the HttpContext property of context object and write there a value. context.HttpContext = new AwesomeHttpContext(features, e.FullPath); I don't want to use reflection. I am almost sure there is a way to achieve the same result. Just I don't find the way.